# Android Studio lowercasing the name of folders contained in the assets folder

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I'm working with a project imported from Eclipse running on the latest version of Android Studio (0.5.7).

I'm facing an issue where one of the folders in my assets folder (assets/Images) is lowercased sometime during the build process (the debug APK contains assets/images).

Not sure if this is a configuration error on my end or an IntelliJ / gradle bug, I wasn't able to find any documentation regarding this.

Edit: 0.5.8 was just released, still seeing the same issue.

Edit2: Tested the exact same project in Eclipse and the assets/Images/ folder is resolved correctly, so this seems to be indeed a gradle / Android Studio issue. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, as we've switched back to Eclipse for now.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't matter.  The [resource docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) note in regard to locale qualifiers,

> Values are case-insensitive. The resource compiler converts directory
>   names to lower case before processing to avoid problems on
>   case-insensitive file systems. Any capitalization in the names is only
>   to benefit readability.

I would expect the same to apply to everything in res/.

Comment: that might be fine for the res/ folder but it causes problem for assets/ as referencing files in the assets folder is case sensitive (which is exactly the problem I'm facing)

Comment: For some reason I had it in my head that assets/ was inside res/.  I can't find anything official that says whether assets filenames are case-sensitive, but here are two SO threads that both say all files in assets must be named in lower case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639943/android-assets-folder-not-added-to-apk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033902/android-assets-with-sub-folders

Comment: Thanks for the research, Kevin! I'm still wondering why my current setup worked in Eclipse but no longer in Android Studio. I'll do some more research and evaluate the status here once I'm done.

Comment: Just tested again in Eclipse, Kevin, and the code runs fine. Might be the fact that Android Studio enforces the files to be named in lowercase.